# MP4 Video not playing in Quicktime on MAC after passing it through php readfile()

Tags: php, video-streaming, readfile

I've spent days searching for a solution to this problem but nothing I try works. Situation is as follows: we host a number of videos on Cloudfront and stream those through our website. (works like a charm)

Premium members need to be given the option to download some of the videos, however, we cannot show the actual URL. For that reason, we've set up the following script, which reads the video from our Cloudfront URL and passes it through the server, that way effectively hiding its location.

Here's the weird part: Although this works fine for some videos, others (with the same encoding) won't play in Apple's Quicktime player, saying that the format is not recognized. If I open the file in VLC it works perfectly fine but Apple is acting up.

Naturally I tried to download the file directly from its URL, and it works just fine in Quicktime. Also, the headers are the same in both, the direct download, and the readfile passthru.

Strangly, though, as I said, other videos with lower resolution work fine using the script. I could not find any reason why resolution should have an effect on this, though. Everything else is equal. Videos are encoded in the H.264 format and are stored in a MP4 container.

Any thoughts on what I can do to fix this issue?

Thanks so much

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: video/mp4'); //tried multiple options here, none work
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=asciifriendly-filename.mp4');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: 1234567890'); //this number IS correct. 100%
ob_clean();
flush();

readfile ( $url );  //points to Cloudfront server
```

Comment: Have you looked inside the file to see whether there are any PHP error messages messing up the stream?

Comment: Did you verify the user gets the complete and correct file? Meaning their md5 hash match, for example.

Comment: Yes.... thanks for pointing that out. The script threw a warning if filesize was too big. Clearly, I've tested this but only with smaller files. Thanks guys, your tips were very helpful!